# data form wizard not found in visual studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

i am new in **.net**, i am creating a project name **Customer Maintenance Project** but i am not able to find **Data Form Wizard** in **visual studio 2010**. also Data Form Wizard is missing from **Templates**: pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen this, and I suspect it refers to older versions of Visual Studio - pre-2005 (based on the 71 version number in the URL). My guess is that it was one of a number of rubbish RAD tools that ultimately wasn't popular, and required too much development to make it effective.

**From Version 2005 onwards, databinding using datasource controls was introduced - along with a number of much improved server controls, which I suspect negated the need for a Form generation wizard**.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. Maybe something you are looking for

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/63h88ca4(VS.80).aspx